# Create nested json object using python jsonpickle

Tags: python, json, jsonpickle

I want to build nested json object using python jsonpickle,

something like this

```
 {"key": "value",    
  "key2": {
          "key2": "value2", 
          "key": "value"}
          }  
 }
```

using jsonpickele set value to variable name and

```
def __init__(self, value):
        self.key1 = value
        self.key2 =' {key:value,key2,value}'
```

and

```
 jsonpickle.encode(obj, unpicklable=False)
```

can generate json object but I need way to create json object like putting key value pair,
like concatenate key value to nested json object inside loop

Comment: Why are you using a string for self.key2?  If it is an actual Python dict, things will work fine (e.g. `self.key2={'key': 'value', 'key2':'value'}`)

Comment: yes, but i need something to append key value to existing json object using jsonpickle

Comment: I don't think this is not necessarily a jsonpickle-related issue.  Couldn't you decode the existing json object (`json.loads('{key:value,key2,value)}')`), add additional keys to the resulting Python dictionary, then re-encode to json (via `json.dumps``)

Comment: thank you @John Paulett bt i'm able to solved, i put that in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can solved as following

```
def __init__(self, value):
        self.key1 = value
        arr={}
        #append value to arr
        arr.update({'key2':'value2'})
        arr.update({'key':'value'})
        self.key2 = arr
```

Then when `jsonpickle.encode(obj, unpicklable=False)` will produce a nested json object we required